# running python from cmd

Tags: python, windows, installation, anaconda

I have python installed through anaconda and have it running in spyder.  Is there a way to run python from a  command shell (cmd) using the installed version from spyder or do I need to install python through the Microsoft store?  Is there an environment variable that I need to set?

Comment: If it is not already the case, you need to add the directory containing the Python executable to the PATH environment variable.

Comment: Just check if your env variables are already set with `python --version` from the command shell. If not set up your environment path and you're good to go. You can read this blog for more information: https://blog.enterprisedna.co/python-set-environment-variable/